# Is $|f'(x)| < \sqrt{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove or disprove the following:

If $f$ is a twice-differentiable real-valued function on the real line such that $|f(x)| \le 1$ and $|f''(x)| \le 1$ for all $x$, then $|f'(x)| < \sqrt{2}$ for all $x$.

I tried using $(f'(x)^2)' = 2f'(x)f''(x)$, which implies $-2f'(x) \le 2f'(x)f''(x) \le 2f'(x)$. I was then trying to use the anti derivative, but this is where I get stuck.

Any help or hits would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Edited my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say we have an $a$ such that $f'(a)=\sqrt2$. Since $|f''(x)|\leq 1$, the triangle with corners at $(a\pm\sqrt2,0)$ and $(a, \sqrt2)$ must lie below the graph of $f'$ (intuitively obvious, but follows rigourously from the mean value theorem). Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, what does this say about $f(a+\sqrt2)-f(a-\sqrt2)$?

The proof of the impossibility of $f'(a)=-\sqrt2$ is completely analogous. As is any proof that $|f'(x)|>\sqrt2$ cannot happen, although that also follows from the intermediate value theorem.